# Description Of Jambudweep In Different Indian Religions

Tags: vedas, puranas, other-religions, geography, cosmology

I have been researching quite a lot on Hindu cosmology and geography. Moreover, I am keen on learning similar geographies of other sub-religions of India, especially those that grew from within Hinduism. The most interesting of all is the description of the seven Dvipas and Samudras.

Jambudweepa, as we know, in both, Hinduism and Jainism, are quite similar if we just mean the overview of it. However, what are the similarities and differences, the every detailing of the mountain ranges, khands, varshas, kshetras, nadi, etc. in each of them?

**References:-**

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlSNhMANkXLWo01YYd2d4xq8g6ge38JDh
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLt8BoySwnO5s3HxtR67Jrd2LvLSawvxL1